# How can I have a button and scroll view in the same spot?

Tags: swift

To build context, my app has a stack of cards (similar to Tinder) that flip and each could contain a lot of text on one side that require a UITextView for scrolling. It's basically a flashcard app, so once the user is done looking at the card, they swipe it away to view the next one.

I'm trying to make it so the user can tap anywhere on the card to flip it, so I added a clear button that fills up the card. My problem is that when the button is at the front, it blocks the text view from being scrollable, and when the button is at the back, the text view blocks it from being pressed.

Is there a way around this somehow to allow for both functionalities?

Comment: You could maybe create a `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, like so:

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap(gesture:)))
addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

And the function to trigger:

```
@objc func tap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Tap!")
}
```

Comment: @ericathanas No problem! 

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the text view itself. Something like:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.didTap(_:)))
textView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

@objc func didTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Handle the tap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try a tableView or a collectionView, you can customize your cell to look like a card then when a user clicks the cell it will flip or present a popup view, thats easier.

Comment: I'm not sure that a tableView or collectionView would be used in this case. I've updated my description to hopefully be more clear, but let me know if it's still not!